# SBT not resolving sbt-heroku plugin dependency

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, playframework-2.2

I'm moving my app from RUN@Cloud to Heroku. I try to deploy the app to Heroku using [sbt-heroku](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku) plugin. The dependency doesn't want to resolve.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.heroku#sbt-heroku;0.1.5: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

sbt version is 0.13.1. The content of Build.scala file:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "happymelly-teller"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    jdbc,
    cache,
    filters,
    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.2-RC2",
    "com.andersen-gott" %% "scravatar" % "1.0.3",
    "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "0.4.0",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.5.0.8",
    "com.heroku" % "sbt-heroku" % "0.1.5",
    //"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.1",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.9",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9",
    "org.joda" % "joda-money" % "0.9",
    "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.4.2",
    "org.planet42" %% "laika-core" % "0.5.0",
    "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.7.3",
    // update selenium to avoid browser test to hang
    "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.39.0",
    "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.3",
    "nl.rhinofly" %% "play-s3" % "3.3.3"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(scalariformSettings: _*).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.url("heroku-sbt-plugin-releases", url("https://dl.bintray.com/heroku/sbt-plugins/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    resolvers += "Rhinofly Internal Repository" at "http://maven-repository.rhinofly.net:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local",
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
    routesImport += "binders._"
  ).settings(
      /* Scalariform: override default settings - no spaces within pattern binders is the only option in IntelliJ IDEA,
        preserve spaces before arguments is needed for infix function syntax (unconfirmed).*/
      ScalariformKeys.preferences := FormattingPreferences().
        setPreference(SpacesWithinPatternBinders, false).
        setPreference(RewriteArrowSymbols, true).
        setPreference(PreserveSpaceBeforeArguments, true)
      // Avoid building Scaladocs and sources to reduce build time.
    ).settings(sources in(Compile, doc) := Seq.empty
    ).settings(publishArtifact in(Compile, packageDoc) := false
    ).settings(publishArtifact in(Compile, packageSrc) := false)

}
```

I tried several versions of the plugin (not only 0.1.5, but 0.1.4 and 0.1.3 also) without any success. Did anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"com.heroku" %% "sbt-heroku" % "0.1.5"
```

also, you should have added the following lines to your `plugins/plugins.sbt` file

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("heroku-sbt-plugin-releases",
  url("https://dl.bintray.com/heroku/sbt-plugins/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.heroku" % "sbt-heroku" % "0.1.5")
```

Comment: I tried "%%" with no success. 

Is there any difference between using resolvers and plugin data in plugins.sbt and Build.scala?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the github.com repo?

Comment: I followed. It didn't help me. I tried to put plugin data both to plugins.sbt and Build.scala

Comment: I did. I tried to put plugin data both to plugins.sbt and Build.scala. In the former case I just got another error: herokuAppName is not found. I supposed it's because there's no plugin.

Comment: Well the former problem should be solved by doing this `herokuAppName in Compile := "your-heroku-app-name"` in your `build.sbt` NOT your `Build.scala`

Comment: When I follow the description in the repo, I get an error "not found: value herokuAppName". When I remove the line "herokuAppName in Compile..." line and simply run "play deployHeroku" I get "Not a valid command: deployHeroku". For me it looks like the dependency isn't resolved and  the plugin is not here. BUT I get no errors "com.heroku#sbt-heroku;0.1.5: not found"

When I move all plugin data from plugins.sbt to Build.scala, I finally start getting unresolved dependency error.